# Replicate the Google Earth Engine satellite basemap for analysis in code editor

Tags: google-earth-engine, imagery, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need high resolution cloud-free raster imagery (<1m resolution) for Montana, USA. Visually inspecting the Google Earth Engine satellite basemap looks to be higher resolution than NAIP imagery (which is the highest resolution I am currently aware of). But I understand that raster analyses can't be conducted on the Earth Engine basemap.  How do I replicate what I'm seeing on the Earth Engine satellite basemap with imagery from the archive to get the same level of resolution?